# fedora 25 server edition cannot mount an external ntfs USB HDD

Tags: fedora, usb

I purchased an external USB HDD box with two 4T HDD (8T in total) and successfully mount it on a Fedora 26 workstation PC, showing two 4TB ntfs drive.

```
[167211.641072] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[167211.768917] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0539
[167211.768919] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=10, Product=11, SerialNumber=5
[167211.768920] usb 3-2: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
[167211.768921] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: JMicron
[167211.768922] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[167211.769966] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[167211.770066] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 152d pid 0539: 4000000
[167211.770101] scsi host5: usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[167212.773747] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD40 EFRX-68N32N0     0X0@ PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[167212.774125] scsi 5:0:0:1: Direct-Access     WDC WD40 EFRX-68N32N0     0X0@ PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[167212.775083] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[167212.775258] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[167212.775261] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] 4096-byte physical blocks
[167212.775561] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[167212.775564] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 3b 00 10 08
[167212.775587] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[167212.775836] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[167212.775843] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[167212.776509] sd 5:0:0:1: [sde] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[167212.776545] sd 5:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[167212.776757] sd 5:0:0:1: [sde] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[167212.776761] sd 5:0:0:1: [sde] 4096-byte physical blocks
[167212.776869] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[167212.777159] sd 5:0:0:1: [sde] Write Protect is off
[167212.777162] sd 5:0:0:1: [sde] Mode Sense: 3b 00 10 08
[167212.777520] sd 5:0:0:1: [sde] No Caching mode page found
[167212.777526] sd 5:0:0:1: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
[167212.778333] sd 5:0:0:1: [sde] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[167212.870855]  sdd: sdd1
[167212.872168]  sde:
[167212.872288] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[167212.872602] sd 5:0:0:1: [sde] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[167212.873183] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[167212.873731] sd 5:0:0:1: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
```

**But on a Fedora 25 server edition**

```
[ 1005.076130] usb 2-10: new high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[ 1005.244860] usb 2-10: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0539
[ 1005.244866] usb 2-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=10, Product=11, SerialNumber=5
[ 1005.244869] usb 2-10: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
[ 1005.244872] usb 2-10: Manufacturer: JMicron
[ 1005.244874] usb 2-10: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[ 1005.288669] usb-storage 2-10:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1005.288765] usb-storage 2-10:1.0: Quirks match for vid 152d pid 0539: 4000000
[ 1005.288807] scsi host6: usb-storage 2-10:1.0
[ 1005.288846] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 1005.296004] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
```

does anybody know why is that? Both PC have `usbcore.autosuspend = 2`
I guess it has something to do with `Direct-Access` ?

Comment: It's possible there is an F25/F26 difference here, not a Workstation/Server one...